# How to use AbstractProcessor in a no-gradle project

Tags: java

@HelloWorld

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface HelloWorld {
    String name() default "";
}
```

MyProcessor.class

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("org.example.HelloWorld")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7)
@AutoService(Processor.class)
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    private Filer mFiler;
    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        super.init(processingEnv);
        this.mFiler = processingEnv.getFiler();
    }

    private static final String SUFFIX = "Test" ;
    private static final String packageName = "cn.lovelycat.ata";
    private static final String retStr = "Generated!";
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(HelloWorld.class)) {
            HelloWorld annotation = element.getAnnotation(HelloWorld.class);
            String name = annotation.name();

            String newClassName = name + SUFFIX;

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
                    .append("package " + packageName + ";\n\n")
                    .append("public class ")
                    .append(newClassName)
                    .append(" {\n\n")
                    .append("\tpublic String getMessage() {\n")
                    .append("\t\treturn \"");
            
            builder.append(retStr).append(" !\\n");

            builder.append("\";\n")
                    .append("\t}\n")
                    .append("}\n"); 

            try {
                JavaFileObject source = mFiler.createSourceFile(packageName + "." + newClassName);
                Writer writer = source.openWriter();
                writer.write(builder.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

I have compiled this processor to a jar, and now I have added this jar to another project as a lib.
Just like this.

```
public class Main {
    @HelloWorld(name = "GeneratedMain")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEZYn.png)

And I tried to build the project, it just generated some files in out dir.
Now I still could not to use the generated class in my project.

How should I do to make it work properly?